# How checkout source from Scala Trac?

Tags: version-control, scala, trac

This is ridiculous. I am trying to download some code from scala trac:

http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala-tool-support/trunk/src/vim

How in the world do I find out which version control tool is used (SVN or git etc...) and what url to use to checkout/clone it?

PS: Great - it also doesn't download the original file - unless I click on the tiny "Original file" link at the bottom.

Comment: Note that there is a fork and enhancement of the vim files at https://github.com/ewiplayer/vim-scala. This is by the guy who does the vim tutorial videos.

Comment: And if you use this svn link: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-tool-support/trunk/src/vim/ you will be able to check out just the vim files with `svn co`. But I would recommend the git fork from Derek.

Comment: Thanks @huynhjl! You led me to discover vim bundles (pathogen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason to not use the official [Github repo](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/tree/master/tool-support/src)?

You can download it with `git clone https://github.com/scala/scala-dist.git`

Comment: Actually are the vim files in the scala repo? They used to be under scala-tool-support which may not be at github.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a search engine with the keywords "Scala SVN" yields: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/213

Comment: I should not be using search engines - it should be right there in the Trac project. Why provide a web-interface to something that I can't get at?

Comment: This is as much a fault of the developers using Trac as the Trac's. They should have put the Readme or something there.

Comment: @drozzy: They changed to JIRA today. Are you happy now?