# Downloading source tree hosted with the trac scm?

Tags: version-control, trac

I have just discovered a SCM entitled "trac", that apparently lets us host source code with revision feature, and so on.

I actually found something interesting at https://brutallogic.net/trac/jcryptic but there is apparently not any link where I could download the source tree as an archive, nor there is any link to clone the repository.

Did anyone ever try to download source code hosted in a remote trac repository and faced a similar issue? How could I perform the downloading process? Is there a tool or shall I write one on my own?

Comment: You should search a bit more before asking, since we already have a lot of good and often relevant answers. Regarding your issue probably one of these would have been enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377729
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044807
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360058

Comment: I've searched for relevant answers and found the first one you pasted. But it doesn't help much since I cannot find any "zip archive" on the trac website I have given. You should read my question a bit more before posting such an unpleasant comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Trac isn't SCM, it's web-frontend with repo-broswer|wiki|tickets to *different* **real** SCMs
2. For any supported SCM you have to have corresponding client and now URL of repository in backend (Trac-URL isn't direct URL to object in repository)

Comment: @GeoffreyR. - I'm not Trac guru, but, I'm afraid, you can't do it from user's side

Comment: It depends on local installation and configuration. Directories *may* be made available for download as archive, see here: http://trac-hacks.org/browser/tagsplugin/tags/0.6 .